# Why do I keep getting the Error: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm working on an `app` for my `A-levels` and while the `app` loads fine, none of my data appears. When I check the debug code I got this error:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

I'm new to Android Studio, so I don't know where to put what adapter.

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference Category;
TextView txtFullName;
RecyclerView recycler_menu;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MakeupViewHolder> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Makeup");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Init Firebase

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    Category = database.getReference("Category");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Set Name for user
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
    txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());

    //Load menu
    recycler_menu = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);

    loadMenu();
}
```

Comment: initialize adapter

Comment: `adapter` is null, because you never assign it anything.

Comment: please create object of adapter before  "recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);"

Comment: null Adapter is handled by RecyclerView initialize it then it will work.

Comment: @HareshRamani What would the format for that look like?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that this is an error that you need to handle. I do not know why the Android team choose to mark this log as "error".

A method called [dispatchLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#RecyclerView.dispatchLayout%28%29) is called as part of the layout phase, and that method should basically do nothing if either `LayoutManager` or `Adapter` are `null`. Which makes sense, and this log is printed in those cases.

It will just disappear when you have set both your `LayoutManager` and `Adapter` to the `RecyclerView`